# Why does Ampère's force only linearly depend on the distance between the two wires?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, charge

When we encountered Ampère's force law our professor stated:

> In the formula of the magnetic force you don't find $r^2$ as in the gravitational and the electric one because while those directly come from properties of matter, namely mass and charge, this still has to do with charge, just in motion.

I feel like this explanation is at least superficial.

Comment: What kind of explanation do you expect? Usually, the $r^2$ is motivated by the fact that the surface of a sphere also behaves $\propto r^{-2}$, and that static forces (those coming from a scalar potential) from point-like objects should behave much the same. The magnetic force is not such a conservative force, hence the argument fails. (this is just rephrasing what your professor said)

Comment: It's just a matter of dimensionality. The electric field generated by an infinite charged plate is constant in modulus everywhere in space, but this is a somewhat unrealistic physical scenario, like the infinite wire.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Something a bit more precise, like yours or Mark's, thanks.

Comment: @Phoenix What do you mean by dimensionality?

Comment: an infinite plate is 2-dimensional, while an infinite wire is 1-dimensional

Comment: @Phoenix Oh sure. For some reason I thought you were referring to something deeper, related to how the different forces behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your professor means, but magnetostatics does obey a $\frac{1}{r^2}$ law, called the Biot-Savart law.

The reason you have a $\frac{1}{r}$ force between two long wires is that you're integrating over the wires. It's no different than the force between two thin lines of charge - that also falls as $\frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: I understand the $\frac{1}{r}$ thing, thanks.

But isn't Biot-Savart law $$B=\frac{\mu_{0}}{2\pi}\frac{i}{r} \ \ ? $$

Comment: @VincenzoOliva No, that's the Ampère Law (or Biot-Savart law) *applied* to the particular case of the long straight current. Mark is talking about the contribution of a short length $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\ell}$ of current $I$ to a total magnetic field at a point with position vector $\mathbf{r}$ relative to the current element: the Biot-Savart law is that this contribution is $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\ell}\times \hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}$.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Oh, I see. Is that something advanced? My (high school) book makes no distinction.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Not really. It's just that you'd need to sum up all the current elements in an integral if the wire weren't straight - the formula you cite wouldn't work for a loop, for example. Your formula is derived making symmetry assumptions that hold for a straight wire so that one doesn't need to do the integral. Ampère's and Biot-Savart laws are equivalent - they can be derived from one another - indeed I always need to look the BS law up and don't remember it.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Understood. It seems my book is rather approximative. Thank you too!